# Automating execution of a command on remote machine with input file

Tags: ubuntu, automation

I need to automate the following workflow.

1. Copying a file (say `inputfile.txt`) to a remote machine (fixed ip) through SSH
2. Logging into that remote machine through SSH (using Remote Desktop Viewer of ubuntu)
3. Running a particular command with that file (`inputfile.txt`) as parameter.

   ```
   mycommand -option inputfile.txt
   ```

I need to be able to right click the file and choose "Execute my mycommand" context menu (Nautilus) item which will run the command in the remote machine. (and hopefully show a message box with the result - not that necessary)

Need suggestions on how to do it.

EDIT:
Figured out copy works this way. Any idea on how to integrate into nautilus menu.
Also the following command prompts for password

> scp -r inputfile.txt user@machine.domain:/home/userremote/Documents

Comment: Do you truly need to run the command using remote desktop? It would e far easier if you could execute the command over SSH, possibly using X forwarding if it's truly a GUI application.

Answer (score 0):

GUI-Programs aren't always easily automated.

The first challenge is the nautilus-script.
What does it contain?

```
cat ~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts/mycommand
```

Maybe you can do it in a more direct way.

```
cat inputfile.txt | ssh REMOTE "mycommand"
```

or

```
cat inputfile.txt | ssh REMOTE "cat - > tmp.txt; ~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts/mycommand -option tmp.txt"
```

or with two commands, scp first.